# How to use link_to with a method and how to route it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, railstutorial.org

I am trying to toggle to administrator any user from my users list, but whenever I try to grant or to revoke the admin status, I am redirected to the "Something went wrong..." page.

I am following the Hartl's tutorial.

I'm just learning Rails. I try this as an exercise, I tried to make my admin_toggle method as the destroy method which works well. Unfortunately they don't work the same and I can't figure out why.

Here the code :

```
# users_controller.rb

class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :logged_in_user, only: [:index, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :correct_user, only: [:edit, :update]
  before_action :admin_user, only: [:destroy, :index, :admin_toggle]
  ...
  def destroy
    User.find(params[:id]).destroy
    flash[:success] = "User deleted"
    redirect_to users_url
  end

  def admin_toggle
    admin = User.find(params[:id]).admin
    User.find(params[:id]).toggle!(:admin)
    if admin == false
      flash[:success] = "User granted"
      redirect_to users_url
    else
      flash[:success] = "User revoked"
      redirect_to users_url
    end
  end
```

And the view :

```
# _user.html.erb (partial)
<% if current_user.admin? && !current_user?(user) %>
   <% if user.admin? %>
      | <%= link_to "ADMIN : revoke", user, method: :admin_toggle, data: { confirm: "Sure ?" } %>
   <% else %>
      | <%= link_to "NON ADMIN : grant", user, method: :admin_toggle, data: { confirm: "Sure ?" } %>
   <% end %>
   | <%= link_to "delete", user, method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Sure ?" } %>
 <% end %>
```

Weird thing, it redirects to /users/ID and gives me the page "Something went wrong..." with no trace as I can get any other time. When I reload /users/ID, it works, but still not modified.

Here are my routes if it can helps :

```
    $ rake routes
         Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                   Controller#Action
          login GET    /login(.:format)              sessions#new
                POST   /login(.:format)              sessions#create
         logout DELETE /logout(.:format)             sessions#destroy
         signup GET    /signup(.:format)             users#new
create_operator GET    /create_operator(.:format)    operators#new
          users GET    /users(.:format)              users#index
                POST   /users(.:format)              users#create
       new_user GET    /users/new(.:format)          users#new
      edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format)     users#edit
           user GET    /users/:id(.:format)          users#show
                PATCH  /users/:id(.:format)          users#update
                PUT    /users/:id(.:format)          users#update
                DELETE /users/:id(.:format)          users#destroy
```

Trace printed in server console : **Loading the Users list. (/users)**

```
Started GET "/users" for ::1 at 2015-07-08 13:56:04 +0200
Processing by UsersController#index as HTML
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
   (0.3ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "users"
  User Load (0.7ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" LIMIT 30 OFFSET 0
  Rendered users/_user.html.erb (9.9ms)
  Rendered users/index.html.erb within layouts/application (26.4ms)
  Rendered layouts/_navbar.html.erb (1.6ms)
  Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.4ms)
Completed 200 OK in 181ms (Views: 178.1ms | ActiveRecord: 1.1ms)


Started GET "/assets/bootstrap.min.self-6655d1384d1509415d234003e6f81cf5de3d688790aaadc1091aa5bb5795b1f1.css?body=1" for ::1 at 2015-07-08 13:56:05 +0200
Started GET "/assets/custom.self-5dd633f307143f76efffe6b3679cac893d31afe43812a2cb92157504e82a4c6f.css?body=1" for ::1 at 2015-07-08 13:56:05 +0200
Started GET "/assets/bootstrap_and_overrides.self-17173183fc31fb911be417d4e28b79f99d056440baa2cf49ce4f6bebb37313a5.css?body=1" for ::1 at 2015-07-08 13:56:05 +0200
Started GET "/assets/operators.self-e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855.css?body=1" for ::1 at 2015-07-08 13:56:05 +0200
Started GET "/assets/sessions.self-e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855.css?body=1" for ::1 at 2015-07-08 13:56:05 +0200
Started GET "/assets/users.self-e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855.css?body=1" for ::1 at 2015-07-08 13:56:05 +0200
Started GET "/assets/application.self-6ebd6dc00e43682c61d8f6c189788df291bca642abcb4b29fb5c478c41c371b6.css?body=1" for ::1 at 2015-07-08 13:56:05 +0200
Started GET "/assets/bootstrap.min.self-075878ec6a19d24f3b46052eb9e0e5bb5c2a098ac50d05d8e3a21309d129273a.js?body=1" for ::1 at 2015-07-08 13:56:05 +0200
Started GET "/assets/jquery.self-d03a5518f45df77341bdbe6201ba3bfa547ebba8ed64f0ea56bfa5f96ea7c074.js?body=1" for ::1 at 2015-07-08 13:56:05 +0200
Started GET "/assets/turbolinks.self-680e388bf7f759d85e2dbe0044d33f55e12b26da721317111c01ec92e53df55e.js?body=1" for ::1 at 2015-07-08 13:56:05 +0200
Started GET "/assets/operators.self-877aef30ae1b040ab8a3aba4e3e309a11d7f2612f44dde450b5c157aa5f95c05.js?body=1" for ::1 at 2015-07-08 13:56:05 +0200
Started GET "/assets/jquery_ujs.self-8e98a7a072a6cee1372d19fff9ff3e6aa1e39a37d89d6f06861637d061113ee7.js?body=1" for ::1 at 2015-07-08 13:56:05 +0200
Started GET "/assets/sessions.self-877aef30ae1b040ab8a3aba4e3e309a11d7f2612f44dde450b5c157aa5f95c05.js?body=1" for ::1 at 2015-07-08 13:56:05 +0200
Started GET "/assets/users.self-877aef30ae1b040ab8a3aba4e3e309a11d7f2612f44dde450b5c157aa5f95c05.js?body=1" for ::1 at 2015-07-08 13:56:05 +0200
Started GET "/assets/application.self-f8806224e027f3e3f0138ea9ce99319e298dfdb323304d1f1be6eae8e8c74724.js?body=1" for ::1 at 2015-07-08 13:56:05 +0200
```

Trace printed in server console : **Clicking the Grant button for User 4**

```
Started POST "/users/4" for ::1 at 2015-07-08 13:58:18 +0200

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [POST] "/users/4"):
  web-console (2.0.0.beta3) lib/action_dispatch/debug_exceptions.rb:22:in `middleware_call'
  web-console (2.0.0.beta3) lib/action_dispatch/debug_exceptions.rb:13:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  railties (4.2.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  railties (4.2.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.2.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
  activesupport (4.2.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
  activesupport (4.2.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
  railties (4.2.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:22:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/runtime.rb:18:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.2) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:113:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:113:in `call'
  railties (4.2.2) lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in `call'
  railties (4.2.2) lib/rails/application.rb:164:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/content_length.rb:15:in `call'
  puma (2.11.1) lib/puma/server.rb:507:in `handle_request'
  puma (2.11.1) lib/puma/server.rb:375:in `process_client'
  puma (2.11.1) lib/puma/server.rb:262:in `block in run'
  puma (2.11.1) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:104:in `call'
  puma (2.11.1) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:104:in `block in spawn_thread'


  Rendered /Users/tomsihap/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/web-console-2.0.0.beta3/lib/action_dispatch/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (2.8ms)
  Rendered /Users/tomsihap/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/web-console-2.0.0.beta3/lib/action_dispatch/templates/rescues/routing_error.html.erb within rescues/layout (69.3ms)
```

Trace printed in server console : **After reloading the webpage, clicking Revoke for User 5**

```
Started POST "/users/5" for ::1 at 2015-07-08 14:00:17 +0200

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [POST] "/users/5"):
  web-console (2.0.0.beta3) lib/action_dispatch/debug_exceptions.rb:22:in `middleware_call'
  web-console (2.0.0.beta3) lib/action_dispatch/debug_exceptions.rb:13:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  railties (4.2.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  railties (4.2.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.2.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
  activesupport (4.2.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
  activesupport (4.2.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
  railties (4.2.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:22:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/runtime.rb:18:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.2) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:113:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:113:in `call'
  railties (4.2.2) lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in `call'
  railties (4.2.2) lib/rails/application.rb:164:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/content_length.rb:15:in `call'
  puma (2.11.1) lib/puma/server.rb:507:in `handle_request'
  puma (2.11.1) lib/puma/server.rb:375:in `process_client'
  puma (2.11.1) lib/puma/server.rb:262:in `block in run'
  puma (2.11.1) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:104:in `call'
  puma (2.11.1) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:104:in `block in spawn_thread'


  Rendered /Users/tomsihap/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/web-console-2.0.0.beta3/lib/action_dispatch/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (2.2ms)
  Rendered /Users/tomsihap/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/web-console-2.0.0.beta3/lib/action_dispatch/templates/rescues/routing_error.html.erb within rescues/layout (66.2ms)
```

I don't understand why it is rooting to /users/5 while the `:destroy` method roots to /users...

Comment: Could you post the error trace printed in server console?

Comment: In your `admin_toggle` method you have assigned value for admin instead of comparing. `if admin = false` . It will always return "User revoked" no matter what. Change it to `unless admin`

Comment: EDIT : 1/ I've misspelled the copy paste : the "=" assignation into the if structure was already a "==" 2/ I've paste the server console trace

Answer (score 2, accepted):

admin = false is assignment, not condition checking.
The following code should work

```
def admin_toggle
  user = User.find(params[:id])
  user.toggle!(:admin)
  flash[:success] = user.admin ? "User granted" : "User revoked"
  redirect_to users_url
 end
```

after toggle, the user object gets updated, and admin attribute reflects the latest status

Make sure you added route for admin_toggle

```
resources :users do
  put :admin_toggle, on: :member
end
```

and check the link_to tag to

```
<%= link_to "ADMIN : revoke", admin_toggle_user_path(user), method: :put, data: { confirm: "Sure ?" } %>
```

Comment: edit : I've misspelled the copy paste : the "=" assignation into the if structure was already a "==" . Thanks a lot anyway ! And so obviously, I'm still getting the same issue, I've edited with the server trace.

Comment: You need to add a route for admin_toggle, check the answer

Comment: Thanks! And here I will be stuck with the routes. I added  `get 'update_admin' => 'users#admin_toggle'` to the routes, doesn't change anything.

Comment: Thanks you @SKR, now it works like a charm ! 
But I don't understand the route and I don't find any documentation online about the "put / do" that you did, could you please explain or give me a doc about it ?

Comment: I've found that the route you gave me gives : `admin_toggle_user PUT    /users/:id/admin_toggle(.:format) users#admin_toggle` . And from the documentation http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html (2.10.1.), I've understood that it gives me a "child" route of /users, that uses the params[:id] given, and to which I can give a HTTP verb to be RESTful. Well all that I needed to do without knowing it !